# Run background tasks after RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-core, asynchronous

I have the following two methods:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateModel(MovieModelVm viewModel)
    {
        var preferences = viewModel.MovieModels.ToDictionary(x => x.MovieId, x => x.Selected);
        await Mediator.Send(new CreatePreferenceCommand { Preferences = preferences });
        _ = GenerateModelAndPredictions();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    private async Task GenerateModelAndPredictions()
    {
        await Mediator.Send(new CreateModelCommand());
        await Mediator.Send(new CreatePredictionRatingCommand());
    }
```

What I want to achieve is to run GenerateModelAndPredictions method, after the RedirectToAction. Basically I want to do some background stuff without blocking the UI.

In the beginning, the first call from that method is being made, but it just aborts with no error.
If I call the method like `await GenerateModelAndPredictions();`, everything is working fine.

I've tried with `ConfigureAwait(false)`, with `Task.Run(() =>GenerateModelAndPredictions())`, basically everything just to avoid the await part so I don't block the UI, but with no success.

I've done some digging, but I don't seem to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found another solution to my problem; using a task scheduler.
I've used Hangfire for this scenario. Basically the methods that I wanted to run in the background will be executed by a job that I schedule before redirecting.

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => GenerateModelAndPredictions());
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to achieve is to run GenerateModelAndPredictions method, after the RedirectToAction.

You can try to create and use an action filter to run your custom method after the `CreateModel` action executed and before reaching into `Index` action, like below.

```
public class ActionFilterForCreateModelAction : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, 
        ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        //before the action executes

        await next();

        //after the action executes

        GenerateModelAndPredictions();
    }

    private async Task GenerateModelAndPredictions()
    {
        await Mediator.Send(new CreateModelCommand());
        await Mediator.Send(new CreatePredictionRatingCommand());
    }
}
```

Apply to `CreateModel` action

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionFilterForCreateModelAction]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateModel(MovieModelVm viewModel)
```

Comment: I've tried with the ActionFilter, but the behavior is the same. I tend to believe that after calling RedirectToAction, because I finish executing the method, Finalize is being called and the process ends. Or maybe IIS is killing the process after RedirectToAction. Correct me if I'm wrong.